# E[1/x] Expectation

Tags: probability

Let X be a continuous random variable with density function

f(x) = 1/30x(1 + 3x) if 1 < x < 3 and 0 otherwise.

We are ask to find E[1/x]. Is that the inverse? ie 1/E[X]

Comment: Unfortunately taking a reciprocal is not a linear operation, and the expectation of the reciprocal is *not* the reciprocal of the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

No. $E[1/X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (1/x) f(x) dx = \int_1^3 f(x)/x dx$.

$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx$. In general, $E[1/X] \neq 1/E[X]$.

Answer (score 0):

No. For a continuous RV $X$, $x \in (1,3)$, then $$E(X) = \int_1^3 xf(x)\,dx$$ Likewise, $$E(1/X) = \int_1^3 \left({1 \over x}\right)f(x) \, dx$$